# EF Core 6 Cosmos provider owned types with "Id" property is mapped as parent entities partition key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-cosmosdb, .net-6.0

I am trying to migrate EF Core 3.1 to 6 and stumbled upon a problem with cosmos provider.

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } // This is a partition key for Orders container.
    public Address? OrderAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address // Owned type
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
}
```

DbContext/ModelBuilder has below setup

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().OwnsOne(x => x.OrderAddress);
```

When a query is issued to cosmos using Ef core like this

```
public IQueryable<Order> FindByAddressId(Guid addressId)
{
    return this.context.Orders!
                .AsQueryable()
                .Where(x => x.OrderAddress.Id == addressId);
}
```

EF Core generates this SQL:

```
info: 3/17/2023 07:05:17.845 CosmosEventId.ExecutedReadNext[30102] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
Executed ReadNext (2264.3513 ms, 5.6 RU) ActivityId='65af0395-363a-47f2-a1a0-d4a1722ae7c1', Container='orders', Partition='7f4cb720-a09f-428b-99d6-03daab9c1d67', Parameters=[]
SELECT c
FROM root c
WHERE (c["Discriminator"] = "Order")
```

This is obviously incorrect because EF Core Cosmos confuses owned type's `Id` with Order's `Id`.

From the SQL log, Partition='7f4cb720-a09f-428b-99d6-03daab9c1d67', This guid belongs to Address type, not an Order type.

But, if I replace the name of property "Id" with a different name like "Xyz", it works!

```
public class Address // Owned type
{
    public Guid Xyz { get; private set; }
}
```

SQL log:

```
info: 3/17/2023 07:19:11.950 CosmosEventId.ExecutedReadNext[30102] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
Executed ReadNext (359.2586 ms, 5.96 RU) ActivityId='9f1105fc-4723-4a3d-91a9-27332e4fef5a', Container='orders', Partition='(null)', Parameters=[@__pid_0='7f4cb720-a09f-428b-99d6-03daab9c1d67']
SELECT c
FROM root c
WHERE ((c["Discriminator"] = "Order") AND (c["OrderAddress"]["Xyz"] = @__pid_0))
```

What could cause this problem? How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need a proper configuration of that model, because of the behavior of **CosmosDB**. It needs explicit configuration to map correct property as a partition key.

Doing this should fix it

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
    .ToContainer("orders")
    .HasPartitionKey(x => x.Id)
    .OwnsOne(x => x.OrderAddress, b =>
    {
        b.Property(a => a.Id).ToJsonProperty("AddressId");
    });
```

Another solution is to simply rename

```
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
```

To

```
    public Guid AddressId { get; private set; }
```

Btw in my previous project we decided to use **CosmosSDK** instead of **EF Cosmos Provider**, since it is new, still doesn't work without problems.

Comment: Sadly, I can't rename the property :(

Comment: Yep, had the similar issue, that's why i suggested to configure it with ToJsonProperty() method

Comment: Wouldn't this change property from the database? 
As I said, I can't change property name from entity i.e poco class and also from document in cosmos.

Comment: @wenn32 I'm facing the same issue. Did you find a way to fix it?

Comment: @rafalxyz I managed to fix it but I cant remember what I did :(

Comment: Sorry, I should have included the answer here when I fixed it.